# vb.net windows service timer.elapsed event not completing all tasks

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

This windows service would check every minute for pending records to be processed, once for the testing site, and once for the production site; I have only 1 subroutine with a parameter to indicate if testing site so the right SQL connection string is used.

I'm using the **Elapsed** event to call the subroutine 2 times but only the first one gets called or processed.

Code:

```
{
Private Shared iMacrosExecuterTimer As Timers.Timer

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        'Initiate and set timer
        iMacrosExecuterTimer = New Timers.Timer
        iMacrosExecuterTimer.Interval = 5000 '5 seconds so it start immediately after it gets enabled, then it will be called every minute
        AddHandler iMacrosExecuterTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
        iMacrosExecuterTimer.AutoReset = False
        iMacrosExecuterTimer.Start()
    End Sub 'OnStart

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    End Sub 'OnStop

    Private Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
        iMacrosExecuterEventLog.WriteEntry("OnTimedEvent: S T A R T E D", EventLogEntryType.Information) 'added for testing purposes
        'Testing Site
        CheckPendingiMacros(True)

        'Production Site
        CheckPendingiMacros(False)
        iMacrosExecuterEventLog.WriteEntry("OnTimedEvent: E N D E D", EventLogEntryType.Information) 'added for testing purposes

        'Re-Start the service again
        iMacrosExecuterTimer.Interval = 60000
        iMacrosExecuterTimer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckPendingiMacros(ByVal TestingSite As Boolean)
}
```

Comment: It only call CheckPendingiMacros(True), even setting the interval under the OnStart to 1 minute.

Comment: You could also try setting the `.AutoReset ` property of the timer to true.If this is false, the event will only be raised once.